# Install GDL for use in Python

Tags: python, wrapper, gdl

I need to use some [GDL](http://gnudatalanguage.sourceforge.net/credits.php) routines from my Python code.

In the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/cenit/GDL/blob/master/PYTHON.txt) of GDL project there is an example very intuitive:

```
>>> import GDL
>>> print GDL.function("sin",(1,))
0.841470956802
```

But, seeing the [INSTALL.MAKE file](https://github.com/cenit/GDL/blob/master/INSTALL.CMake) from the repo, it appears that I have to build GDL as a Python module. The question is: How I can build/install GDL in order to be used as a Python module, like the example before?